# How to post to the new NewsChannel via discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm wanting to make my bot be able to post to the new ANNOUNCEMENTS_CHANNEL feature Discord.com recently rolled out globally through-out the platform, however the discord.js documention is very minimalistic on this feature however they state `NewsChannel extends TextChannel`.

I know this does have a `.send()` but unsure on how to confirm its a `NewsChannel` and is an active announcement channel activated when creating a community guild.

I would love some tips and advice on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that the channel is an anouncement channel, check the type of the channel "news". From that, you can easily just send a message into that channel like you would normally do with a normal text channel.

```
let channel = message.mentions.channels.firts()
// ^^ An option if you are getting the channel from a mention in the message

if (channel.type !== "news") return
channel.send("your message")
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel

Comment: Thank you for this, as this actually was something similar to what I wanted.